# Access session data from parent controller w/o passing it in

Tags: laravel

Can I access session data from `Controller`, without passing the request from `MyController`?

```php
class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // ** next line throws error:
        // "Session store not set on request."
        $userdata = request()->session()->get('userdata');

        // I want to inject `userdata` into every template without
        // passing data from child controllers.
        view()->share(['userdata' => $userdata);
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        // This works, so the data is in fact in the session.
        // I don't want to pass it, or `$request` to the parent from here.
        $userdata = $request->session()->get('userdata');
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using

Comment: I'd like to avoid adding that dependency to every controller if I can avoid it. similar to the reason for having a parent controller in the first place. Seems odd I cannot access session data outside the scope of a request object. Not the end of the world if it's not possible in Laravel.

Comment: @RossWilson 5.8

Comment: can't u use `session('key')`? Like `$var = session('userdata')`

Comment: @MateusJunges I tried that too, but it just returns null from the parent controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it won't be working in your `__construct()` method is because the `StartSession` middleware won't have been run yet.

To get around this you can simply use the `middleware()` method on the controller:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {

        $userdata = $request->session()->get('userdata');

        view()->share(compact('userdata'));

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

---

[Laravel 5.3 Upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0) (Scroll down the **Controllers** section)

> In Laravel 5.3, you can't access the session or authenticated user in your controller's constructor because the middleware has not run yet.
>   As an alternative, you may define a Closure based middleware directly in your controller's constructor.

Comment: Thanks Ross! It's just missing parens after `session`:  `$request->session()->get('userdata');` (I edited it)

Comment: @Coder1 Glad I could help! :) Sorry about the typo.